# react redux: still getting empty object for this.props when using Connect for mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, create-react-app

I'm trying to follow this tutorial (https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3) on React Redux but am getting an empty object when I print out this.props. It seems like mapStateToProps isn't actually setting this.props since react redux's connect isn't being called, but I'm not sure why

This is what the state should be (like in the tutorial), all I did was change the component's name ItemList to Home

[image]

Here's what I'm getting (nothing was mapped to the state):

[image]

actions/items.js

```
export function itemsHasErrored(bool) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED',
        hasErrored: bool
    };
}

export function itemsIsLoading(bool) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_IS_LOADING',
        isLoading: bool
    };
}

export function itemsFetchDataSuccess(items) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
        items
    };
}

export function itemsFetchData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(itemsIsLoading(true));

        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((items) => dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(items)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

components/Home.js

```
export class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props)
  }

 render() {

    if (this.props.hasErrored) {
      return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
    }

    if (this.props.isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading…</p>;
    }

  return (
      <ul>
          {this.props.items.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                  {item.label}
              </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
  );    

  }
}


 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      items: state.items,
      hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
      isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

reducers/index.js

```
export function itemsHasErrored(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED':
            return action.hasErrored;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function itemsIsLoading(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_IS_LOADING':
            return action.isLoading;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function items(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.items;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

store/configureStore.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'

import { Home }                     from './components/Home'
const store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {

    render () {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Home />
        </Provider>
      )
    }

  }
```

index.js (I am using create-react-app boilerplate)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Did you check the store contents to see if the items are there? I'd suggest you install the redux dev tools, which makes looking at this really easy.

Comment: Also, are you calling `this.props.fetchData` at any time? I'm not seeing that in your code.

Comment: And in your screenshot, you're looking at the props of `Provider`; `Home` is the component that the store state will map props to.

Comment: I get fetchData is not a function when I do this.props.fetchData() inside componentDidMount(), and nothing was mapped to the Home component

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue is that you're exporting two components... the non-connected (via the named export `Home` with `export class Home...`) and connected (via `export default`). Then, you're importing and rendering the non-connected component:

```
import { Home } from './components/Home'
```

Since you want to use the *connected* component, you should be importing the *default* export like this:

```
import Home from './components/Home'
```

You may want to just export the connected component, unless you have some reason to use the unconnected one.

Comment: holy shieeet, you are a life saver, thank you so much!!

Comment: My pleasure, @user3226932!

Comment: I literally spent 3h to understand why my application is not working and the problem where two small braces. Here's my upvote!

Comment: I am making the same mistake even today.  This answer helped me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was a simple issue, but without your help, I would have ended up scratching my head definitely for a few hours :)